# Colorbox maxHeight clips my images

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I am using Colorbox to display high definition pictures on my site. Some of the pictures are portrait, some are landscape. I set the colorbox settings to have a `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` and it works ok for the landscape oriented pictures.

The problem is that the portrait pictures are displayed as landscape pictures, but zoomed in and clipped in half. Landscape pictures are also clipped to some extent, depending on window size.

How do I get colorbox to automatically scale all images so that the entire image fits nicely inside the window, disregarding the orientation or size?

See the illustration below for a demonstration of the problem.

[image]

Comment: can you set max-height property to image? Something like `$('#colorbox img').css('max-height','600px');`

Comment: That may be part of a solution. I can set the `max-height:100%` using CSS, then the image fits, but the width of the Colorbox/controls stays the same.. also tried `$.colorbox.resize({width: $myImg.width() })` in the `onComplete` callback, did not work

Comment: @VitaliiMaslianok Actually it did work, I used the wrong selector :-)

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution (though not optimal) thanks to Vitalii Masilianok tip about max-height

In the colorbox css I set:

```
#cboxContent img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

And then I have to use the `onComplete` callback to resize the Colorbox:

```
$(".gallery").colorbox({
    maxWidth: "95%", 
    maxHeight: "95%",
    transition: "none",
    onComplete: function() {
        $.colorbox.resize({ width: $('.cboxPhoto').width() })
    }
});
```

Using this solution I remove the transition, otherwise I get awkward sizeup-sizedown transitions between each slide.

Comment: This answer is great except it adds scroll bars to the bottom of each image (colorbox).  Any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: @Dave_P Not sure exactly what is happening for you, but sounds like you could try `overflow-x: hidden;` as a CSS rule for the image container (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Try this attitude:

1. Compute the `widthRatio` as imageWidth / winWidth, `heightRatio` as imageHeight / winHeight
2. Compute the ratio as `Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio)`
3. Set the image size to original `imageWidth / ratio` and original `imageHeight / ratio`
4. Hook the function on `window.load` and `window.resize`

See this code

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
var origWidth = image.offsetWidth, origHeight = image.offsetHeight;

function setImageSize() {
    var winWidth = window.innerWidth, winHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var ratioWidth = origWidth / winWidth, ratioHeight = origHeight / winHeight;
    var ratio = Math.max(ratioWidth, ratioHeight);
    // var ratio = Math.max(ratio,1); uncomment this not to enlarge small images
    with(image.style) {
        width = origWidth / ratio - 20 + "px"; // 10 px margin
        height = origHeight / ratio - 10 + "px";
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load",setImageSize);
window.addEventListener("resize",setImageSize);
```

in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUUnk/)